# jenkins: setting root url via Groovy API

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I'm trying to update Jenkins' root URL via the Groovy API, so I can script the deployment of a Jenkins master without manual input (aside: why is a tool as popular with the build/devops/automation community as Jenkins so resistant to automation?)

Based on [this documentation](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/JenkinsLocationConfiguration.html#setUrl(java.lang.String)), I believe I should be able to update the URL using the following script in the Script Console.

```
import jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration
jlc = new jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration()
jlc.setUrl("http://jenkins.my-org.com:8080/") 
println(jlc.getUrl())
```

Briefly, this instantiates a `JenkinsLocationConfiguration` object; calls the setter `setUrl` with the desired value, `http://jenkins.my-org.com:8080/`; and prints out the new URL to confirm that it has changed.

The `println` statement prints what I expect it to, but following this, the value visible through the web interface at "Manage Jenkins" -> "Configure System" -> "Jenkins URL" has **not** updated as I expected.

I'm concerned that the value hasn't been update properly by Jenkins, which might lead to problems when communicating with external APIs.

Is this a valid way to fix the Jenkins root URL? If not, what is? Otherwise, why isn't the change being reflected in the config page?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are creating a new JenkinsLocationConfiguration object, and updating the new one, not the existing one being used

use

```
jlc = JenkinsLocationConfiguration.get()
// ...
jlc.save()
```

to get the one from the global jenkins configuration, update it and save the config descriptor back.

see : https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/jenkins/model/JenkinsLocationConfiguration.java

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. However after running my script above, if I open a new script terminal, and construct `jlc = new jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration()` then `println(jlc.getUrl())` still prints the updated URL `http://jenkins.my-org.com:8080/`.

Comment: do not forget to save the config after updating it. see http://pghalliday.com/jenkins/groovy/sonar/chef/configuration/management/2014/09/21/some-useful-jenkins-groovy-scripts.html for some examples.

Comment: Wow, that article is exactly what I've been looking for!

Comment: This was also quite handy for me and this question: https://github.com/docksal/service-jenkins/blob/master/groovy/default-config.groovy