# Setting the Jenkins root URL from code/script console fails

Tags: jenkins

I a trying to figure out how to set the jenkins root url:

[image]

from code. I have tried - bit of a wild guess:
[image]

But that gives the error shown above.

Any suggestions on how to set that property from code/script?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355079/jenkins-setting-root-url-via-groovy-api

Comment: URL is configured at installation time. However you could change it in security section. Why do you need change it?

Comment: Its part of automatic installation/deployment of jenkins